# Index entire array backwards in for loop

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I would like to loop over an array and within the loop index the array forward and backward for all of its indices like so:

```
x = np.random.uniform(size=600)
for i in range(len(x)):
    dot = np.dot(x[:-i], x[i:])
```

Now this doesn't work, because `x[:-0]` is just like `x[:0]` which gives `[]`.
I could handle the zero case separately but was wondering whether there's a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an end of slice value of `-i or None`. If `i` is non-zero, then it's just `-i`, but if it's `0`, then `-0` is falsy, and it evaluates and returns the second term, `None`, which means "run to end of sequence". This works because `foo[:None]` is equivalent to `foo[:]`, when you omit that component of the slice it becomes `None` implicitly, but it's perfectly legal to pass `None` explicitly, with the same effect.

So your new line would be:

```
dot = np.dot(x[:-i or None], x[i:])
```

Comment: It pairs well with "truthy". :-) I prefer to use it over "true" and "false", because frankly, in Python, you rarely care about the actual values `True` and `False`, you just care whether a value is true or false for boolean evaluation purposes; truthy or falsy makes it clear you care about the meaning, not the specific value.

Comment: I see you've played knifey spoony before https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcE0aAhbVFc

Comment: Neaty. I would probably go with [:len(x) - i], but that's only because I'm paranoid about relying on boolean evaluation of non-booleans.

Comment: @RuneLyngsoe: Yeah, that also works, though it would be slower (particularly if you didn't precompute `len(x)` outside the loop and store it off; the overhead for calling built-in functions like that is surprisingly high given how little work they actually do). `-i or None` only adds a single implicit boolean evaluation (about the cheapest thing CPython can do shy of the `pass` statement) to the common case, where `len(x) - i` adds a built-in lookup, built-in call, and subtract operation to every usage (local load and subtract if you precache would cost only a trivial amount more at least).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the length information:

```
length = len(x)

for i in range(length):
    dot = np.dot(x[:length-i], x[i:])
```

Comment: I think they want a slice smaller than the length of x

Comment: @Pureferret it is smaller than the length of x (except for the first iteration)

Comment: yup, this is equivalent to ShadowRanger's solution, thanks!