# Python whole reverse list specifying index

Tags: python, list

I have a list that I want to get the last few elements of in reverse order:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
```

I can reverse the list with `lst[::-1]` and get the whole list reversed. But I want the reversed list only up to a certain index. I can specify an index:

```
ind = 1
lst[:ind-1:-1]
```

and get:

```
[4, 3, 2]
```

which is the original list up to the specified index, in reverse order. This works for any index > 0. But if ind is 0 (meaning the whole list should be returned, in reverse order), this causes a problem:

```
ind = 0
lst[:ind-1:-1]
```

returns:

```
[]
```

because my ending place is the same as my beginning (-1). My expected/desired output would be `[4, 3, 2, 1]`

I know an easy workaround would be to just put an if statement to catch the case where ind is 0, or do it in two steps (index then reverse), but it feels like this should be doable with the indexing system in Python. Am I wrong?

Comment: What *do* you want if **ind** is 0?  You're getting exactly what you specified.

Comment: The whole list in reverse order, the same as `list[::-1]`. I've edited the question to state this, thanks.

Comment: Could you add some example input and output if `ind` was `0`?

Comment: If you must do it with slicing, just use `None` if `ind == 0`, e.g. `lst[:None if ind==0 else ind-1:-1]`.

Comment: `lst[:-5:-1]`, but that feels unreadable.

Comment: @JoshLee to make this generic you would need `lst[:ind-1-len(lst):-1]`...

Comment: @AChampion Ah! Looks like we have a winner! Seems obvious now...

Comment: @AChampion you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`None` can be explicitly provided to indicate "to end"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42674711/364696) (for negative step, the "end" is the beginning of the sequence):

```
lst[:ind - 1 if ind else None:-1]
```

While you did say you were avoiding the two step approach, it's frankly simpler to do it that way; unless you expect the slice to be huge, the simplicity gain is worth whatever trivial performance loss you might suffer:

```
lst[ind:][::-1]
```

For the record, on trivial microbenchmarks, assuming each `ind` value is equally common, the one-step approach is faster, but the difference is fairly small unless your `list` is huge. For example, for your four element `list` using `ipython` for microbenchmarking:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> %%timeit -r5 inds = range(len(lst))
... for ind in inds:
...     lst[:ind-1 if ind else None:-1]
...
1000000 loops, best of 5: 791 ns per loop

>>> %%timeit -r5 inds = range(len(lst))
... for ind in inds:
...     lst[ind:][::-1]
...
1000000 loops, best of 5: 1.1 µs per loop
```

That's slower, but the cost is only about 300 ns. Even when `lst` is len 4000, the difference is 18 vs 35.5 ms per loop; granted, that's nearly doubling the time, but if it's not performance critical (or the lists are usually smaller), I'd call that acceptable, since it eases maintainer burden to read "slice from ind to end, then reverse it" rather than the more complicated structure of the one step slice.

Comment: Like @juanpa.arrigillage, I would probably leverage `reversed()` vs. `[::-1]`, as it reads cleaner, but this is purely a personal style thing.

Comment: @AChampion: I'd use `reversed` if I were iterating it once and throwing it away (`for x in reversed(lst[ind:]):`). If I actually need the result as a `list`, I prefer `[::-1]`; it's 100% idiomatic in Python (I read `[::-1]` for what it is at least as fast as `reversed`), and significantly faster as a bonus (using `list(reversed(lst[ind:]))` in those same microbenchmarks gets timings that take 50-150% longer than the two-step solution with `[::-1]`). It's also more type friendly; if I'm performing this slice on some other sequence type (e.g. `str`, `tuple`) I get the same type back, not `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy technique is use

ind = 1

lst[:ind:-1] = This will reverse the list of values from the mentioned index.